# What is the largest resolution image I can print at a store with a print center?

Tags: print-design, resolution, image-quality, digital-printing

My company prints cheap posters relatively frequently for events we host and attend. Usually we print these posters at a Sams Club down the road from our offices. We have had a history of files refusing to show up on the Fujifilm kiosks at the print center in the store, requiring numerous trips and guessing games. Obviously I want to get the highest resolution prints we can get, but after doing some research, I haven't been able to find any resolution or dimension information regarding what either Sams Club or the Fujifilm Kiosks will handle.

Does anyone know the maximum resolution, dimensions, or any other information that can help me figure these systems out? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is something that you should ask *them* about, not us

Comment: Normally, I would expect the problem is file size during transfer rather than resolution, but ( http://help.samsclub.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/1738/~/how-to-upload-photos ) says maximum individual file size is "68063mb" maximum. This is 63GB. I am...skeptical.

Answer (score 1):

Resolution or dimensions?

For "resolution" ask what machine they are working with and google the specs. In real life print an image, either you like it or you do not.

For sizes, again, go to your local store or call them and ask.

The "guessing games" is probably your game. You need to ble clear on what information you need to know. One thing is a color calibration issue, where you need to print a sample and come back with some adjustments, but "dimensions" just make a call.

Answer (score 1):

Well, with the info we have here we can only give you some general guidelines.

For the dimensions part, depends on the size of the poster, do you want it A3, that is **297mm** by **420mm**, resolution is safe to have it at **300 pixel/inch**.

This will give you a document of exactly **3508 x 4961 pixels**.
Anything other than that, is just as you called it, a guessing game. Ask them about this, it's a lot easier and it's actually the best thing to do.

If they don't know what to tell you, do what @Rafael suggested: "*ask what machine they are working with and google the specs*".